# Data Formate almost done, But does not show candlestick chart

Tags: javascript, json, laravel

Frist send data view page than json_encoded array data by Laravel. json_encode after var livetrde = '';
livetrdeObj = jQuery.parseJSON(livetrde);
Data formate almost done. I can't understand why does not show my chart data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCAY6.png)

`for($i=0; $i<$different_days; $i=$i+$day){

```
            $data[$i] = TradingProduct::where('group_product_id', $group_product_id)
            ->whereBetween(TradingProduct::raw('date(created_at)'), [Carbon::now()->subDays($i+$day), Carbon::now()->subDays($i)])
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'ASC')
            ->get();

        $liveTrade = [];
        $arrData = [];
        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $arrData[$key] = $value;
            $open = [];
            $high = [];
            $low = [];
            $close = [];
            $arrPrice = [];
            $time = [];

            $dd = 15;
            $j = 0;
            foreach ($arrData[$key] as $arrDatakey => $arr) {
            
                if(!empty($arr['price'])){  

                $arrPrice[$arrDatakey] = $arr['price'];
                $time[] = $arr['created_at'];

                $open = reset($arrPrice);
                $high = max($arrPrice);
                $low = min($arrPrice);
                $close = last($arrPrice);

                

        $start_date_time = Carbon::now()->subDays($j);

            $end_date_time = Carbon::now()->subDays($j+$dd);
            $different_days_time = $start_date_time->diffInDays($end_date_time);
        $currentTime = $start_date_time->subDays($different_days_time)->timestamp;

        $j = $j+$dd;
        }
    }

    $liveTrade[] = '{x: new Date('.$currentTime.'), y: ['.$open.','.$high.','.$low.','.$close.']}';

 }
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here in creating the `$liveTrade[]` data. You are using Date() as string where it should create an object *(Note that I'm already formatting the date in php itself in the format `'Y-m-d'` which can be changed as per your needs)*. Update it to be like this:

```
 $liveTrade[] = '{x: ' . (date('c', $currentTime)) .', y: ['.$open.','.$high.','.$low.','.$close.']}';
```

The better solution would be to push and array into `$liveTrade[]` and later in the end convert it into json like below:

```
  // within the foreach loop you need to convert timestamp to date
  $liveTrade[] = array('x' => date('c', $currentTime), 'y' => [$open, $high, $low, $close]);
  // use date('D M d Y H:i:s O', $currentTime) to mimic JS date object
 
// ... Before returning response
$response = json_encode($liveTrade);
echo $response;
```

Comment: {x: Mon Jan 19 1970 21:04:32 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time), y: Array(4)} please give me formate, But got {x: "Fri Jan 01 2021 03:37:14 3", y: Array(4)} this formate.

Comment: Change the formate type in date() as per your needs. I changed it to 'c' which refers to global UTC timestamp. You can change it after referring this url https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Also check this https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_format.asp